# OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:<Object_NAME> is not defined

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to call a VF page from Salesforce custom button.
the code is as follow written under the button.

```
 OnClick JavaScript:
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 
 window.location= 'apex/PrintExpenseInfo?id='+ Medical_Event_vod__c.id;
```

Can anyone poitn out where is the issue? Its giving me an error like - 
"A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: is not defined

Comment: its working now with below format - window.open('/apex/PrintExpenseInfo?id={!<ObjectName>.Id}');

Answer (score 0):

working now with below syntax -

```
       window.open('/apex/PrintExpenseInfo?id={!Medical_Event_vod__c.Id}');
```